# Why tensorflow Synchronous distributed blocked

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, distributed-computing

**show codes:**

```
    cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": self.train_args['ps_hosts'], "worker": self.train_args['worker_hosts']})
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name=self.job_name, task_index=self.task_index)

if self.job_name == "ps":
    log.info('server is running..............')
    server.join()
else:
    log.info('worker: {} is running..............'.format(self.task_index))
is_chief = self.task_index == 0

with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device="/job:worker/task:{}".format(self.task_index), cluster=cluster)):
    self.cnn = self.init_model_class()

    self.global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False)
    lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate=0.005, global_step=self.global_step,
                                    decay_steps=self.train_args['lr_decay_steps'],
                                    decay_rate=0.96, staircase=True, name='learn_rate')
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr)
    grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(self.cnn.loss)

    if self.train_args['is_sync']:
        rep_op = tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer(optimizer, replicas_to_aggregate=len(self.train_args['worker_hosts']),
                                                total_num_replicas=len(self.train_args['worker_hosts']),
                                                use_locking=False)
        self.train_op = rep_op.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=self.global_step)
        if is_chief:
            init_token_op = rep_op.get_init_tokens_op()
            chief_queue_runner = rep_op.get_chief_queue_runner()
    else:
        self.train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=self.global_step)

    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables(), save_relative_paths=True, max_to_keep=10)
    all_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    if not os.path.exists(self.checkpoint_dir):
        os.makedirs(self.checkpoint_dir)
    sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(self.task_index == 0),
                             logdir=self.checkpoint_dir,
                             init_op=init_op,
                             summary_op=all_summary_op,
                             saver=saver,
                             global_step=self.global_step,
                             save_model_secs=60)
    session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=self.train_args['allow_soft_placement'],
                                  log_device_placement=self.train_args['log_device_placement'],
                                  device_filters=['/job:ps', '/job:worker/task:{}'.format(self.task_index)])

    with sv.managed_session(server.target, config=session_conf) as self.sess:
        if self.task_index == 0 and self.train_args['is_sync']:
            sv.start_queue_runners(self.sess, [chief_queue_runner])
            self.sess.run(init_token_op)

        batches = data_process.batch_iter_train(self.train_args['batch_size'], self.train_args['num_epochs'])

        local_step = 0
        for x_batch, y_batch in batches:
            local_step += 1
            current_step = self.train_step(x_batch, y_batch)
            if current_step % self.train_args['evaluate_every'] == 0:
                log.info('worker: {} global step: {} local step: {}'.format(self.task_index, current_step, local_step))
                x_dev, y_dev = data_process.batch_iter_dev(self.train_args['dev_batch_size'])
                self.dev_step(x_dev, y_dev, current_step)


        sv.stop()
        log.info('****************************finish training***********************************')
```

I use 4 machines, 3 for worker(same hardware: 24 cpus), 1 for ps

**question**:

1. when i use asynchronous distribute, worker 0 and 1 use 50% cpu, but worker 2 just spent 15% cpu, why?
2. when i use Synchronous distributed, worker 0 blocked after trains 1 step, and other workers blocked too without doing nothing, i try to start worker 1,2 before worker 0, but nothing change, why?
3. does all checkpoints are stored on worker 0? with my codes, why the checkpoint only store one checkpoint, i set save last 10.

   saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables(), save_relative_paths=True, max_to_keep=10)
4. how about summary? store on diff machine or just worker 0, i find 3 workers have summary.

anyone can give me some advices, thanks very much! did i use it with wrong way?